# How do I implement cascading dropdowns in PHP and AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, ms-access, odbc, cascadingdropdown

I need some serious help or advise on something that I've spend countless hours on researching and coming up empty.

I have a project where I need to pull data from an MDB database using PHP.
I have succeeded in connecting to the database, I can query the database and display the results in a table and I can even search the database using a text input.

My client wants an advanced search functionality with multiple dropdowns. These dropdowns are getting the values from the database. All this is still fine. I can populate the dropdowns from the database.

The database is a vehicles database (Id, Stock Number, Make, Model, Year, Price, Features etc). Unfortunately all the vehicle data is in one table. So for example, there are four ASTON MARTIN cars in the database, each with it's own ID and model.

I know that it would be best to have at least two separate tables: make and model. But the database is generated by a third party application which saves a copy of the database to the server and that's the one I connect to.

The question is: using PHP and AJAX, would it be possible to have cascading dropdowns when drawing data from the same table? So for example, if I chose ASTON MARTIN from the Make selection, the second dropdown would only show the models related to ASTON MARTIN?

Please see the below attempt at trying this... This script successfully loads the Make column from the database to the first dropdown, and the Modal column from the database to the second dropdown, but they are not linked. As it currently is, the first option is ASTON MARTIN and it's corresponding model is CORSA (That's not at all correct).

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

          function loadXMLDoc() {
          var xmlhttp;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.frm.modelSelection.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
       }

        var makevalue=document.frm.makeSelection.value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","?ajaxmake="+makevalue,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
            }

            </script>

            <?php 

            $dbName = "C:/xampp/htdocs/new/db/savvyautoweb.mdb";

            // Throws an error if the database cannot be found
            if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
            die("Could not find database file.");
            }

            // Connects to the database
            // Assumes there is no username or password
            $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

            ?>

            <form action="" method="post" name="frm">
        <select name="makeSelection" onchange="loadXMLDoc()">

            <?php
         $resultMake = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Make FROM Vehicle ORDER BY Make") or die (odbc_errormsg());
         while ($rowMake = odbc_fetch_array($resultMake)) {
     echo "<option value='$rowMake[Make]'>$rowMake[Make]</option>";
         }
              ?>
           </select>
           <select name="modelSelection">

            <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxmake'])) {
        $resultModel = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Model FROM Vehicle") or die (odbc_errormsg());

         while ($rowModel = odbc_fetch_array($resultModel)) {
           echo "<option value='$rowModel[Model]'>$rowModel[Model]</option>";
         }

         die();
             }
                 ?>
             </select>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
                 </form>
```

*EDIT* brought on to code above based on your solution. Thank you for this.

The function seems to work, but it populates the second dropdown with the make column and not the model column. Any idea why?

Thank you, Deon Jonker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your select, you could add an onchange attribute like this

```
<select name="makeselection" onchange="filtermodelselection()">
```

You add a function filtermodelselection(), which reads out the selected option from your makeselection like (give a name to your form, or an id to your select, I'll use "frm" now as formname)

```
var makeid=document.frm.makeselection.value;
```

You send your ajax request to the page. then with the makeid you can make an ajax request to the server like this : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get_unique

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.frm.modelSelection.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
var makevalue=document.frm.makeSelection.value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","?ajaxmake="+makevalue,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On the server side you get a $_REQUEST['ajaxmake'] variable.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxmake'])) {
   //do the magic the query, and then echo like what you did here:
while ($rowModel = odbc_fetch_array($resultModel)) {
    echo "<option value='$rowModel[Model]'>$rowModel[Model]</option>";
}
//then die, to not echo anything else accidentally
die();
}
```

example output:

```
<option value='AUDI'>AUDI</option>
<option value='BMW'>BMW</option>
```

on the recieving side, with ajax you give the recieved value from the server to the modelSelection's innerHTML.like:

```
document.frm.modelselection.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

If something is not clear, please feel free to ask.

EDIT:
put this part:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxmake'])) {
        $resultModel = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Model FROM Vehicle") or die (odbc_errormsg());

         while ($rowModel = odbc_fetch_array($resultModel)) {
           echo "<option value='$rowModel[Model]'>$rowModel[Model]</option>";
         }

         die();
             }
   ?>
```

to the beginning of the file. (after any includes, database connector codes of course)

Comment: Thank you for the response. So what would the filtermodelselection() function look like? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "On the server side, you make the query which filters the models, then you could send back the options as string with echos"? I'm really green when it comes to AJAX/Javascript.

Comment: I've updated it for you. forgot to edit the onreadystatechange. hold on a second

Comment: edited the onreadystatchange. Note that this is not the nicest solution, it would be nicer, to remove the options one by one, then add them one by one instead of this innerHTML dump. But that would be more complicated

Comment: Thank you very much. I made some adjustments to the original question. The function seems to work, but it populates the second dropdown with the 'Model' column and the 'Make' column. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: I can't imagine the situation. The second dropdown lists both the Models and the Makes?

Comment: You have to check if it's an ajax call before every other output. If you dont do that, that would be dumped into the select element too. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: could you write down your sql query?

Comment: Yes the second dropdown lists both.

Comment: The SQL Query looks like this:

Comment: 'Make': $resultMake = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Make FROM Vehicle ORDER BY Make") or die (odbc_errormsg()); | 'Model': $resultModel = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Model FROM Vehicle") or die (odbc_errormsg());

Comment: The only problem could be that, you accidentally dump both of them. could you update your code in the original post to show your php/sql? I could tell the mistake exactly then

Comment: The post is updated... I can't see where both are being dumped... I'm not sure where to use the example output you have in your original answer... Am I supposed to use that somewhere?

Comment: I've updated my answer, put your code before anything else. Other codeparts run before the ajax handling, and it's not good in that way.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'll give that a try when I'm back in the office tomorrow morning... you've been a great help...

Comment: Hi... Thank you for that... If I do what you suggested, the 'Model' drop down appears before the 'Make' drop down... it does populate the 'Model' drop down with only the Models from the database... but it's still not linked to the correct make... so if I select Aston Martin from the Make drop down, it still comes up with incorrect model...

Comment: "SELECT Model FROM Vehicle" rewrite this query to this : "SELECT Model FROM Vehicle WHERE Make = '".$_REQUEST['ajaxmake']."'"

Comment: Hi, I've done what you suggested by rewriting the query. What happens now is it loads the correct models to the selected Make, but it still loads all of the Makes as well. So If I select BMW it loads all of the BMW models, but it loads all the Makes also.

Comment: There are 2 cases. In the first case, the Makes are on the top of the list. It means, that your ajax handling php code is not running first. In this case, move your code as far up as possible. In the second, if the Makes are the last options, the code doesn't exit after you echod the results. Make sure the die(); is in the right place